# Entity framework - Linq GroupBy data from multible tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I want to group data (using Northwind as an example) by Order.CustomerID.

IN SQL it looks like this :

```
Select
  o.CustomerID,
  SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1-od.Discount))

FROM Orders o INNER JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
```

How do I load that data using Linq?

I tried

```
var order = context.Customers.Include("Orders.Order_Details")
            .SelectMany(x => x.Orders)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Customer = x.Customer,
                Sum = x.Order_Details.Sum(y => (float)(y.Quantity * y.UnitPrice) * (1 - y.Discount))
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Key.CompanyName,
                Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Sum)
            });
```

But the query that's produced is ugly and too long.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to group, since all the entities are already linked:

```
context.Customers.Include("Orders.Order_Details").
    Select(c => new
    {
       Customer = c,
       Total = c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o. Order_Details).
                        Sum(d => d.Quantity * d.UnitPrice * (1-d.Discount))
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a one-to-many relationship between Customers and Orders: every Customer has zero or more Orders, and every Order belongs to exactly one Customer.

There is also a one-to-many relationship between Orders and OrderDetails: every Order has zero or more OrderDetails and every OrderDetail belongs to exactly one Order.

Furthermore an OrderDetail has a Quantity, a UnitPrice and a Discount.

Now, given your SQL statement, you want all Orders grouped into groups of Orders for the same Customer. And from every Group you want the CustomerId, and the sum of the price of all OrderDetails of all Orders in this Group.

There are several methods you could do this using LINQ. You tried to start with all Customers:

```
var totalOfAllOrdersOfCustomers = dbContext.Customers
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        CustomerId = customer.Id,
        TotalAllOrders = customer.Orders
            .SelectMany(order => orderDetails)
            .Select(orderDetail => orderDetail.Quantity * orderDetail.UnitPrice
                   * (1-orderDetail.Discount))
             .Sum();
    }
```

In words: from every Customer, take the Id. Also take all OrderDetails of all Orders of this Customer (= `SelectMany`). From every OrderDetail calculate the price using the formula, and sum all these prices.

This would give something very similar to your SQL query. However, there is a difference: if you have a Customer without any orders, you still get a record with the CustomerId and a Sum equal to zero.

If this is what you want, you should use this method.

To get the Customers without any Orders, internally the SQL will do a left outer join from Customers table with Orders table. You can't find Customers without Orders by looking at the Orders table only.

Your SQL statement showed that you didn't want the Customers without any Orders. If that is the case, you don't have to use the Customers table to get your result:

```
var totalOfAllCustomersThatHaveOrders = dbContext.Orders
    .GroupBy(order => order.CustomerId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        CustomerId = group.Key,
        TotalAllOrders = group.SelectMany(group.OrderDetails)
            .Select(orderDetail => orderDetail.Quantity * orderDetail.UnitPrice
                   * (1-orderDetail.Discount))
            .Sum();
    }
```

In words: take all Orders. Put them into groups of Orders with the same CustomerId (= `GroupBy`). From every Group take the `Key` (which is the CustomerId of all Orders in the group) and assign it to CustomerId. The second part is similar to the first solution: Take all OrderDetails from all Orders in this Group (= `SelectMany`) and calculate the price of the OrderDetail according to the formula. Finally Sum all these prices and assign this sum to TotalOrders

So the first one needs an extra left outer join, because it gives you Customers without Orders. The second one is a bit simpler, but if won't give you the Customers that has not ordered anything yet.

Note that in your end result all you know about your Customer is the Id. If you fetch some Customer data immediately after this statement anyway ("oh, now that I've got the CustomerId, I'd like the Customer Name and Address"), I'd use the first method, start with the Customer table and Select all Customer properties you want. This will save you one database roundtrip.